# How to check if Linux user namespaces are supported by current OS kernel

Tags: linux, containers, sandbox, linux-namespaces

After doing some reading, I found that Linux user namespaces are generally supported in Linux versions >= 3.8. However, there's a possibility that user namespaces are disabled on a given OS, making the check for kernel versions unreliable. Is there a robust way to check if the current OS I'm using supports user namespaces and has it available to use?

Comment: make a `uses_namespace` script that just tries to use a specified namespace and returns true/false ? Good luck.

Answer (score 10):

You could check if your current process' `/proc/[pid]/ns/` directory has a file called `user`:

```
ls /proc/self/ns
```

Answer (score 9):

There are two places you can check to see if your kernel supports user namespaces:

1. `/boot/config-*`. (find out which one you are actually using with `uname -a`)
2. `/proc/config.gz`.

In both files look for `CONFIG_USER_NS`. If it reads `CONFIG_USER_NS=y` you're golden. If not, well, you're about to compile a new kernel.

Comment: Arch Linux puts it in `/boot/config.gz`, no?

Answer (score 1):

Provided you are running bash (you can check by running `echo $0`, expected result is `-bash`). Then you can run the following one liner:

```
if [[ `sudo cat /boot/config-$(uname -a | awk '{print $3}') |grep '^CONFIG_USER_NS'` == "CONFIG_USER_NS=y" ]]; then echo "You have support for User Namespaces"; else echo "Sorry, you don't have support for User Namespaces"; fi
```

Comment: Note that here the usage of `sudo`, `cat` and `awk` is superfluous. Instead, you could do something like this:

`if grep -q 'CONFIG_USER_NS=y' /boot/config-$(uname -r); then echo "You have support for User Namespaces"; else echo "Sorry, you don't have support for User Namespaces"; fi`